# Can a double beam of 2x12 handle a span of 16 feet for a patio roof?

Tags: patio, support, cover

I want to build a patio cover. The total area for the roof is 20ft x12ft ( regular roof shingles to match the house) . I want to use only 2 post( 6'x6')  per side , at  16 feet between centers with 2 feet overhang per side.  Rafters ( 2 x 10) would be on 16" centers.  Can the double 2x12 header beams handle a span of 16 feet?

Comment: Do you have a snow load to worry about?

Comment: Not really. I am in San Antonio. We do get some snow,  but it's years in between. I did not look at that. let me see what i can find

Comment: looks like 5psf for ground snow

Comment: So you're going to buy 20' lumber?

Comment: If going that long, I'd expect a manufactured beam would be the best bet...

Comment: Yes, that was my approach. I had nit considered a manufacture beam. I assumed the cost would be greater than double beams, plus I was thinking the beams would sandwich the post, and I would have a strong joint.